# How to override css using class over css using id?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In editing wordpress theme I am having these types of issues. Here is html code:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation span8" style="margin-top:30px" role="navigation">
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#site-navigation li a, #site-navigation li.home.current-menu-item a {
    color: #efa9bd !important;
}

.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a, .main-navigation .current_page_item > a, .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I just want to override `.main-navigation` attributes over `#site-navigation` attributes.

Comment: Then include the styles in your `#site-navigation` selector... If you don't have access to that CSS for whatever reason, then simply override those styles in a CSS you do control. You could also include an ID from higher up your tree for greater specificity (e.g. `#someId .main-navigation` The only way you can override a style applied with an ID selector over a class selector is with `!important`, which you should try to avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the !important from the .main-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove !important from #site-navigation

Answer (score 0):

remove !important from #site-navigation li a. or if it is needed, write color: #efa9bd!important; as inline css. eg:
`<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation span8" style="margin-top:30px" role="navigation" style="color: #efa9bd!important;">`